# Resizing images html/css/jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, resize

I was looking throught internet the way to figure out how [this](http://www.ferrater.com/) have been made.

If you resize the window, always have the same proportion, but also it's not the full image in there.

I've been trying some CSS code, but it's not like it.

```
.res {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

I saw that there's a slider, but the core must be in the CSS, I think so. Or may is in some part of a javascript code?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a jQuery Plugin for this take a look! It´s great!

http://demo.andreaseberhard.de/superbgimage/demo.html

Ah, here is another css only solution, with css3. Taken from css-tricks.

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: And here is a css only solution. certenly this is build with tables http://www.ringvemedia.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 max-width:100%;
 max-height:100%;
```

Comment: thanks, but if I put max-height: 100%; it doesn't fill the window with the image. they posted a demo that does what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the code, you see that it's made using this:

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/

So, it's mostly Javascript code. The code of course uses CSS to control the layout.

Comment: yes, i saw they used royal slider, thanks for checking it too. anyway, will need a slider that can do it for me, as @chris posted!